# Runtime Locatable Code

Tags: computer-science

I have read **Runtime Locatable code** in a discussion forum, Actually what is that rumtime locatable code mean?

Comment: A link to said forum post would be helpful.

Comment: It was an interview questions forum. sorry don't know that exactly..

Comment: When you google for it, you get a lot of interview questions from Philips. Looks like they made it up. :D

Comment: ya.. but i didn't get the answer for that clearly

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of possibilities for what they're referring to, but what strikes me as most likely is actually called Relocatable code: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relocation_(computer_science)

> relocation is the process of replacing
>   symbolic references or names of
>   libraries with actual usable addresses
>   in memory before running a program. It
>   is typically done by the linker during
>   compilation (at compile time),
>   although it can be done at runtime by
>   a relocating loader.